# What do limits of functions of the form $te^t$ have to do with l'Hopital's rule?

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

I have an improper function that I have to integrate from some number to infinity. Once integration is done, the function is of the form $te^t$.
What I'm wondering is what does this have to do with l'Hopital's rule?

From reading my book, I see the following:

> We know that $e^t \to 0$ as $t \to -\infty$, and by l'Hopital's rule we have
>
> $$\lim_{t\to-\infty} te^t = \lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{t}{e^{-t}} = \lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{1}{-e^{-t}} = \lim_{t\to-\infty} -e^t = 0.$$

I know what l'Hopital's rule is

> The limit of a quotient of functions is equal to the limit of the quotient of their derivatives.

I don't understand what this has to do with the explanation above. Can somebody help me understand this please?

Comment: $\infty\cdot0=\infty\cdot\dfrac1\infty=\dfrac\infty\infty\quad$ or $\quad\infty\cdot0=\dfrac10\cdot0=\dfrac00$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice we're trying to evaluate the limit of a product which yields an *indeterminant form*:
$$\lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} te^t.$$

Considering the limit as is yields $-\infty\cdot0$. To avoid this, we utilize l'Hopital's rule.

Now to apply l'Hopital's rule, we need to write $te^t$ as a quotient, i.e., $\dfrac{t}{e^{-t}}$. We now can use l'Hopital's rule to evaluate the limit.

$$\lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} te^t = \lim\limits_{t \to -\infty} \dfrac{t}{e^{-t}} \underbrace{= \lim\limits_{t \to - \infty} \dfrac{(t)'}{(e^{-t})'}}_{\mbox{by l'Hopital}} = \lim\limits_{t \to - \infty} \frac{1}{-e^{-t}} = \lim\limits_{t \to - \infty} -e^{t} = 0.$$
Hence, we see $\lim\limits_{t \to - \infty} te^t = 0$.

So, regarding the improper integral you are solving: can you apply a similar trick to evaluate the limit you're left with?

Comment: So you can just divide them like that to use l'Hopitals rule? The function that I'm interested in specifically is -5xe^(-1/5x). So this should be -5$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} 5e^( -1/5x ).$$ After l'Hopital's rule is applied right?

Comment: Not quite. Notice I had to negate the power of $e^t$ to place it in the denominator. So here, (negating the power of $e^{\frac{-1}{5}x}$) we have:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} -5xe^{\left(\frac{-1}{5}x\right)} = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{-5x}{e^{\left(\frac{1}{5}x\right)}}.$$

Be careful in evaluating this limit; l'Hopital's rule doesn't yield -5.

Answer (score 1):

The invocation of l'Hôpital's rule is
$$ \lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{t}{e^{-t}} = \lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{1}{-e^{-t}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

In $\dfrac t {e^{-t}}$, both the numerator and the denominator go to $\infty$ as $t\to-\infty$.

Comment: Well, numerator goes to $-\infty$...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : Hardly worth mentioning.  Find $\left(-\lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}\dfrac{-t}{e^{-t}}\right)$, and they both go to $+\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, I realized that. But your statement is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^t=\frac{1}{e^{-t}}$, We have $$ \lim_{t\to-\infty}te^t=\lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{t}{e^{-t}}$$

By the l'Hôpital's rule, we go on

$$ = \lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{1}{-e^{-t}}. $$

By the equation $e^t=\frac{1}{e^{-t}}$ again, we have

$$ \lim_{t\to-\infty} \frac{1}{-e^{-t}}=\lim_{t\to-\infty}-e^t=0.$$